# NUXT Redirect issue when making a POST request to external API

Tags: api, nuxt.js

I have a form that I built in Nuxt. I'm trying to submit it to an external API. The expected response is a JWT token.

```
  async login() {
      const res = await this.$axios.$post(`/api/token`, {
        username: this.username,
        password: this.password
      }, this.headers )
       console.log(res)
    }
```

Trying to call the API directly gets me a CORS error, so I use proxy settings in my nuxt.confix.js.

```
...
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/proxy'
  ],
  axios: {
    baseURL: '/',
    proxy: true
  },
  proxy: {
    '/api/': { target: 'https://<apiurl>.com/', changeOrigin: true }
  },
...
```

Now when I check the network tab, it shows a 301 redirect, but the data that was sent in the post request gets thrown away, and it makes a get request to the API which returns a 405 error (because it's expecting a POST request with a data and not an empty GET request).

How can I make a POST request to an external API using NUXT? Is this an option at all?

I tried changing changeOrigin: false, and that seems to get rid of the issue, but it throws a 500 server error instead and an npm error that says

```
 ERROR  [HPM] Error occurred while proxying request localhost:3000/api/token to https://<apiurl>.com/ [ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID] (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

Thank you

Comment: Try for this config:   axios: {
    credentials: true
  }

Comment: That didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not how to send api to an external API ... the problem is in the external API it self ... make sure the external API has no credentials required to make any action ...

if you can make a request to https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts and get results that means there is no problems in your code ... cors erros in most cases are backend issue ... which means .. the backend developer who worked on it should fix it

Comment: After searing up and down that his api could accept calls from my app, he changed the api and it now works

Comment: @mediabloke Glad to hear that :)